# to make password less login to same linux server with same user

Tags: linux

I have performed below steps to make password less login

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa

copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub into authorized_keys

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

but still unable to make password less login. debug logs as below

```
[amt@Test-mViewReport:/apps/amt]> ssh -v amt@10.114.8.161
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.114.8.161 [10.114.8.161] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /apps/amt/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /apps/amt/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /apps/amt/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host '10.114.8.161 (10.114.8.161)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 1e:8a:ad:78:86:1d:59:50:75:b1:8f:a3:8a:3c:9b:b4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/apps/amt/.ssh/known_hosts).
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /apps/amt/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /apps/amt/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /apps/amt/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
amt@10.114.8.161's password:
```

Comment: You copied it into the authorized_keys of the _remote_ side?

Comment: there is no remote server here
i am doing on same server with same user.

Comment: Check your `sshd_config` for the `RSAAuthentication`, `PubkeyAuthentication` and `AuthorizedKeysFile` parameters. Make sure they fit your needs and restart your server in case changes were necessary.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I had performed same procedure on another server and its works fine. but on this server its failing. ssh config is fine for this server.

Comment: Do you know why it can't add the host to `known_hosts`?  Does the `.ssh` directory have the correct permissions (i.e., `700`)?

Comment: Can we get `ls -la ~/.ssh` ?

Comment: Did you try `ssh-copy-id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested I'd start by checking the .ssh directory has permissions of 700. Make sure no other users have write permissions to your home directory. If another user can write to your home directory then they could change/alter anything including the .ssh folder. I allowed group write permissions to my home directory and OpenSSH refused the connection until I reset the perms.

Comment: please improve your answer